# Can't return the length of array when looking for substring

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I return the length of an array when a substring criterion is met? I have three arrays:

```
arr1 = ["V1","V1","V1","V1","V1","V2","V2","V2"...]
arr2 = ["A1","A1","B1","B1","B1","A2","A2","A2"...]
arr3 = ["V1A1*","V1A1*","V1B1*","V1B1*"...]
```

How do I return the length of the filtered arr3, where arr1[i]+arr2[i] is a substring of the element? ("V1A1")

The expected output here would be 2, for the first iteration. (i=0)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by _"the length of arr3"_? The `.length` of the array `arr3` should not change as a result of iterating one or more of the arrays.

Comment: Have you tried anything? In that case add it to your question, that may help to understand what you actually want. It is unclear right now...

Comment: arr3.filter(function(x){return x.indexOf(arr1[i]+arr2[i]) > -1}).length;

That's what I've tried so far.

Comment: @Tincdawg, If one of the answers below solved the problem, please click the checkmark next to the best answer so that everyone else knows that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're saying that these three arrays are the same length, and for each index `i` of the array, you want to know if `arr1[i] + arr2[i]` is a substring of `arr3[i]`.  Then, you want to know how many elements meet this criterea.

To accomplish this, you'll want to look over the indices of the array and use the `string.indexOf` method to see if your criteria is met.

```
var length = arr1.length,
    matchCount = 0,
    isMatch, i;

for(i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf
    // indexOf returns the array index where the substring is found, or -1 if it is not found
    isMatch = arr3[i].indexOf(arr1[i] + arr2[i]) > -1;
    if (isMatch) {
        matchCount += 1;
    }
}

console.log(matchCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

With includes we check whether arr1[i]+arr2[i] is a sub-string of arr3 or not and based on that we filter.

```js
let arr1 = ["V1","V1","V1","V1","V1","V2","V2","V2"]
let arr2 = ["A1","A1","B1","B1","B1","A2","A2","A2"]
let arr3 = ["V1A1*","V1A1*","V1B1*","V1B1*", 'just for test']

let op = (arr3.filter((e,i)=>e.includes(arr1[i]+arr2[i])) || [] ).length

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the matches and the length of said matches you can use `filter`. This assumes you want to know the match for each value not an aggregate of the matches.

```
for (i=0; i < arr1.length-1; i++) {
  const combinedValue = `${arr1[i]}${arr2[i]}`;
  const matches = arr3.filter(e => e.indexOf(combinedValue) > -1);
  console.log(`Number of matches for ${combinedValue}: ${matches.length}`);
}
```